# How to solve the differential equation using integrals.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y(t), t\in (a, b)$, be a real valued smooth function such that $[0, 1]\subset (a, b)$. Suppose that  $y(t)$ satisfies the differential equation $$y''(t)+w(t)y(t)=\lambda y(t)$$ for some real constant $\lambda$. Further, suppose that $y(t)>0$ for all $t\in [0, 1]$ and $y'(0)=y'(1)=0$. Given that $$\int_0^1 \bigg(\frac{y'}{y}\bigg)^2\ dt=10$$ and $$\int_0^1 w(t)\, dt=20.$$
Show that $\lambda=30$.

I tried it by integrating the given differential equation from $0$ to $1$ to see that $$\int_0^1w(t)y(t)\, dt=\lambda \int_0^1y(t)\, dt.$$ But I don't know how to proceed forward? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $y(t)>0$ for all $t\in [0, 1]$, we may divide each side by $y(t)$, and get
$$\frac{y''(t)}{y(t)}=\lambda-w(t)$$
Integrate each side, and we get
$$\int_0^1 \frac{y''(t)}{y(t)}=\lambda-\int_0^1 w(t)dt$$
where $\int_0^1 w(t)dt=10$, so we get
$$\lambda=\int_0^1 \frac{y''(t)}{y(t)}+10$$
Note that
$$\int_0^1\frac{(y'(t))^2}{(y(t))^2}dt=\int_0^1\left(y'(t)\cdot\frac{y'(t)}{y^2(t)}\right)dt=\left[y'(t)\left(-\frac{1}{y(t)}\right)\right]_0^1+\int_0^1\frac{y''(t)}{y(t)}dt=20$$
where we have used IBP in the second equality, and the fact that $\frac{d}{dt}\left(-\frac{1}{y(t)}\right)=\frac{y'(t)}{(y(t))^2}$. Plugging this above, we get $\lambda=30$.